# Starting Apache fails without error

Tags: apache, powershell

I have an Apache service 'SERV[XYZ]' in my Windows services and I would like to be able to start it from a PowerShell script.

In the script, I added variable holding service name:

```
$serv = "SERV[XYZ]";
stop-service $serv;
start-service $serv;
```

but this does not start the service.  PowerShell executes without error.

Comment: Do you happen to have `$ErrorActionPreference` set to `SilentlyContinue` or `Ignore`?

Comment: Also a possibility (if the service name is correct): the service might start and then immediately stop because of a configuration problem.

Comment: Where would I check to see how that is set?  Sorry, I am novice to powershell and services.  Thanks Trevor

Comment: Hi briantist, the service is exact copy of what is displayed in Windows Services->service name and it is "SERV[XYZ]" name for an Apache service.  Apache spawns 2 processes but there could be more based on trafic and they all show as httpd.exe *32 in Task Manager, but power-shell command [Get-WmiObject -ComputerName "localhost" -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | where { $_.Name -like "httpd*" }] will list them as 'httpd', 'httpd#1', 'httpd#2' etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*-Service` cmdlets do [wildcard matches](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the service name. See for instance the documentation of [`Start-Service`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849825.aspx):

> **Parameters**
>   **-DisplayName<String[]>**
>
> Specifies the display names of the services to be started. *Wildcards are permitted.*

The pattern `[XYZ]` means "match any of the characters X, Y, or Z" (like in regular expressions), so your statements try to stop/start services named `SERVX`, `SERVY` and/or `SERVZ`. To match a literal string `[XYZ]` you need to prevent the square brackets from being treated as special characters, e.g. like this:

```
$serv = 'SERV[[]XYZ[]]'
Stop-Service $serv
Start-Service $serv
```

If you have only one service whose name starts with `SERV` you could also use a pattern like `SERV*`, or perhaps `SERV?XYZ?` where the `?` (wildcard matching a single character) mask the square brackets.

Another option would be to use `Get-Service` without a name and filter the results via `Where-Object`:

```
$serv = 'SERV[XYZ]'
Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $serv } | Stop-Service
Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $serv } | Start-Service
```

Comment: Ansgar, Using 'SERV[[]XYZ[]]' works but would you provide more info about what to search for to read about this.  I tried searching for "powershell escape character" but that tells me to use either "'" or "''" (single or 2 single quotes).  But that did not work, I tried both like "SERV'[XYZ']" and like "SERV''[XYZ'']" but neither would work.  So, I would just like to educate my self bit on that in the case I run into scenario where something other than [] are used.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @dbnex14 Added some links to my answer. Check particularly the first one for an explanation on wildcards. As per the documentation you should be able to escape special characters like square brackets with backticks, but when I tested it neither ```SERV`[XYZ`]``` nor ```SERV``[XYZ``]``` worked.

Comment: Yes, that is the site I checked before replying to you.  I tried it too, and it was not working.  So, neigher SERV'[XYZ'] nor SERV''[XYZ''] will work but SERV[[]XYZ[]] works fine.  Much appreciated